# iText7 for .NET - error while merging files

Tags: c#-4.0, itext, itext7

I've created simple method that allows me to merge multiple PDF files.
Below is my code:

```
private void Merge(List<string> src, string dest)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    PdfDocument pdfDocument1 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src[0]), new PdfWriter(dest));

    for (int i = 1,max=src.Count; i < max; i++)
    {
        PdfDocument pdfDocument2 = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(src[i]));
        var pagesCount = pdfDocument2.GetNumberOfPages();
        pdfDocument2.CopyPagesTo(1, pagesCount, pdfDocument1);
        pdfDocument2.Close();
    }
    pdfDocument1.Close();
    sw.Stop();
    Debug.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);
}
```

I've based my code on example from iText book: http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/merging-pdf-documents/clone-merging-documents-bookmarks

For test purpose I've attached that method to button and I'm caling it like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string dest = @"E:\final.pdf";
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\PDFS", "*.pdf").Take(100).ToList();
        Merge(files,dest);
    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
    }
}
```

From time to time (after n'th click on that button) I get exception saying:

> Cant cast from 'iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfNumber' to
>   'iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfStream'.

Also first time I click my application takes about 100MB of memory, next time I click it increase to 150MB, next click and I get 230MB of memory used, so it look like it isn't releasing memory.

Is there a better way to merge multiple PDF's into one using iTextSharp 7?

As per request I'm adding StackTrace:

```
w iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfPage.GetContentStream(Int32 index)
w iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfPage.Flush(Boolean flushXObjects)
w iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfPage.Flush()
w iText.Kernel.Pdf.PdfDocument.Close()
w iTextSharp7_Merge.Form1.Merge(List`1 src, String dest)
w c:\Users\Misiu\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\iTextSharp7_Merge\Form1.cs:wiersz 75
```

And here are exception details:
[image]

EDIT:

I've changed button click function so now it loads 100 file names from directory and calls `Merge` method 10 times with same list:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        string dest = @"E:\final.pdf";
        var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\PDFS", "*.pdf").OrderBy(x => x).Skip(0).Take(100).ToList();

        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(i);
            Merge(files, dest1);
        }
        sw.Stop();
        Debug.WriteLine(sw.Elapsed);

    }
    catch (Exception exception)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exception);
    }
}
```

This way I've excluded random sort of `Directory.GetFiles`.

Here is sample output that comes from Visual Studio:

```
'iTextSharp7_Merge.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Configuration\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Configuration.dll'
1
'iTextSharp7_Merge.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Misiu\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\iTextSharp7_Merge\bin\Debug\itext.kernel.dll'
'iTextSharp7_Merge.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Users\Misiu\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\iTextSharp7_Merge\bin\Debug\itext.io.dll'
A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in itext.kernel.dll
2
3
The thread '<No Name>' (0x2dd0) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
4
5
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in itext.kernel.dll
```

Comment: The exception sounds like your PDF in certain entries contains mere numbers where streams are expected. This in turn either means invalid PDFs or wrong expectations of iText. To check, can you (a) also post the stacktrace of the exception and (b) share a sample PDF for which this happens?

Comment: I agree with @mkl, it would be great if you were able to share your pdf files, or at least a stacktrace. The way you are merging files is correct. Please also take a look at `PdfMerger` class. Please also use `itext7` tag for questions related to iText 7. By the way, for version 7, `iTextSharp` word is no longer used. It is simply called `iText7 for .NET`.

Comment: @mkl I've updated my question with StackTrace and exception details (sorry it's in Polish). Maybe I didn't wrote that clearly, but first time I click merge button everything works fine, second or sometimes third click (same input files, same output) I get that error.

Comment: @AlexeySubach I've fixed title of my question and added StackTrace and exception details, maybe they will help

Comment: You `Take` 100 file names from a list of PDF files from that directory you retrieve using `Directory.GetFiles`. According to msdn *the order of the returned file names is not guaranteed*. If that directory contains more than 100 files, therefore, there might be an invalid one among them which only sometimes is included in the 100 you take and, therefore, only sometimes causes a problem. Thus, are there more than 100 PDFs in that folder?

Comment: @mkl I've tried with `var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"E:\PDFS", "*.pdf").OrderBy(x => x).Take(100).ToList();` and have same result - error occurs from time to time. I'll update my question with another piece of code. This time I'm taking files once and calling Merge method 10 times for same list.

Comment: There also is a `System.NullReferenceException` in your output. How and when does that occur? Probably it is the cause for the later casting issue...

Comment: @mkl First time I call `Merge` method. I've checked that with multiple PDF's, even simple PDF that is saved from Word gives me that error when merging

Comment: A `NullReferenceException` in the first `Merge` call reminds me of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39160630/1729265). You might want to try the solution, probably it helps for your main issue, too.

Comment: @mkl I'm adding compiled DLL from https://github.com/itext/itext7-dotnet/releases to my project, but I'll try that. Maybe You could add pull request that will fix that error?

Comment: @Misiu That fix is already well known to iText development.